# Read files between two dates in a folder Python

Tags: python, date

I am trying to read file names in a folder between `startdate` and `enddate`. (`Datestamp` on file name)

I'm trying something like this. 
Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?
I have thousands of files in that folder but based on start/end date values, often I will have a small percentage files between them.

```
startdate = "05/05/2013"
enddate = "06/06/2013"
mypath = "C:\\somepath\\"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
for filetoread in onlyfiles:
  filesBetweenDate = [ f for f in time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',   time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(somepath+filetoread ))) if f > startdate and f < enddate]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you rearrange the files into a more convenient folder structure?  Something like C:\\somepath\\2013\\05\\05, C:\\somepath\\2013\05\\06, etc.  Each month's folder would hold up to 31 files.  That should make the loop more efficient, instead of creating a huge list of onlyfiles[].

Comment: @BrentWashburne Unfortunately not. The files in the folder are accumulated by an external program that I do not have any control on..

Comment: @U2EF1 After I read the files, I have to do some manipulations on it. It takes around 2-3 seconds now for the entire process. I have 3300 files. But the number of files in that folder will grow up fast.

Comment: You can probably shave a tiny amount off by converting startdate and enddate to seconds since epoch once, outside of your list comprehension, and doing the comparison directly to the return value of `os.path.getmtime`.  I don't think that'll help a lot, but if you're constrained by the external program's behavior every little bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

This avoids the walk through the folder:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.strptime('05/06/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.strptime('06/05/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
filesBetweenDate = []
while start <= end:
    f = start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    if isfile(join(mypath,f))
        filesBetweenDate.append(f)
    start += timedelta(1)
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that there are dates in the file paths.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, with a couple of nice extra features, and only a single pass through the loop.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
import os
import glob, os

mypath = "/Users/craigmj/"
timefmt = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
start = calendar.timegm(datetime.strptime("20130128 00:00:00", timefmt).timetuple())
end = calendar.timegm(datetime.strptime("20130601 00:00:00", timefmt).timetuple())

def test(f):
    if (not os.path.isfile(f)):
        return 0
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(f)

    return start<=ctime and end>=ctime

files = [f for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(mypath, "*")) if test(f)]
for f in files:
   print(f)
```

First off, I use `glob.glob` so that you can use a wildcard in selecting your files. This might save you time if you can be more specific about the files you want to select (eg. if you files contain the datestamp in the filename).

Secondly, I use `ctime` in the `test` function, but you could as easily use `mtime` - the last modification time.

Finally, I'm time-specific, not just date-specific.

The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is whether this is all timezone safe. You might want to check that with an example, before digging through the docs to decide.